# python unittest for a folder recursion method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a method that iterates a folder recursively and generates a dictionary of the files within and their corresponding sizes.

```
`
def get_contents(folder_name) -> dict:
    for item in os.listdir(folder_name):
        item_path = os.path.join(folder_name, item)
        if os.path.isdir(item_path):
            get_contents(item_path)
        else:
            file_name = str(item_path)
            <some code>
    return some_dictionary`
```

I'm trying to write a unit test for the if statement using mocks for os.listdir(), os.path.join() and os.isdir().

These are the return values that I have specified for the patches.

```
`
def test_get_contents_dir_pass(self):
    with patch('mymodule.os.listdir') as list_mock:
         with patch('mymodule.os.path.isdir') as checkdir_mock:
              with patch('mymodule.os.path.join') as path_mock:
                   with patch('builtins.open', new_callable = mock_open()) as mock_file:    
                        list_mock.return_value = ['somedir']
                        path_mock.return_value = 'testapp/somedir'
                        checkdir_mock.return_value = True
                        actual = get_checksum('testapp')
                        assert <some assertion>`
```

I get the below error (I was able to test through adding some debug code, that the if statement/check is definitely executed/reached).
**E   RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
!!! Recursion detected (same locals & position)**

My unit test for the else statement works fine.

I believe it is an issue with my mocks and their return values, but I'm not exactly sure what. Any insights/tips are welcome.

I have tried different permutations of the return values for list_mock and path_mock but to no avail.